# Stream files to Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: c#, azure, http, stream, azure-blob-storage

Consider the following code:

```
 var container = new BlobContainerClient(...);
 // fileStream is a stream delivering 10 MB of data
 await container.UploadBlobAsync("name-of-blob", fileStream);
```

Using Fiddler Proxy to watch the HTTP requests, I can see that this ends up in 4 HTTP PUT requests (the address is 127.0.0.1 as I am locally testing using the Azurite emulator):
[image]

The first two requests (603 and 607) are 4 MB in size, the third one (613) is 2 MB in size and the fourth one (614) finally commits all sent blocks.

1. Instead of making 3 requests (4 MB + 4 MB + 2 MB) for the data, is it somehow possible to stream the 10 MB of data in one request to save some overhead?
2. As the data is sent in 4 MB chunks, does this mean that the Azure Storage clients wait until it got 4 MB from the `fileStream` to start sending, meaning 4 MB of RAM is used for caching? My intention to use a `fileStream` was to reduce memory usage by directly passing through the fileStream to Azure Blob Storage.

I am using `Azure.Storage.Blobs` version 12.8.0 (the latest stable version as I am writing this).

Answer (score 2):

Ad 1) The maximum size of a single block in a PUT operation depends on the Azure Storage server version (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Understanding-Block-Blobs--Append-Blobs--and-Page-Blobs?redirectedfrom=MSDN#about-block-blobs)). For testing purpose I just created a new storage account in Azure and started an `UploadBlobAsync()` operation with a 10.5 MB video file, Fiddler shows me this

[image]

A single PUT operation with 10544014 Byte. Note the `x-ms-version` request header which gives the client the ability to specify which version it wants to use (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob#request-headers-all-blob-types)). I suppose your local emulator is just using an older API version.

Ad 2) Yes, for larger files `UploadBlobAsync()` will chunk the request, reads a set of bytes from the stream, performs a PUT, reads the next set of bytes, performs a PUT and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply. On my side I see a 2020-something (forgot the exact version) version on the headers. Maybe it's just with the Azurite emulator, will suspend further research until I run it on Azure. About the request chunking (ad 2 of your reply), do you know which buffer size `UploadBlobAsync()` uses?